# Best practice for seperating a ASP.Net MVC site with AD from different AD Groups?

Tags: asp.net, authentication, model-view-controller, active-directory

I've got a ASP.net MVC site that authenticates against Azure Active Directory.  I have users in Groups in AD and need to be able to show different navbar items and pages depending on what group the user is in.

Currently I have a shared layout .cshtml for everyone for the navbar and am including or excluding navbar items using code like below.  I am passing in the logged in user and the group they should be in to a helper and then checking to see if that helper is in the group:

```
@if (Helpers.AuthenticationHelper.HasPermissions(User, "IT") == true)
{
    <span>User has access to IT</span>
}
else
{
    <span>User has no access to IT</span>
}

@if (Helpers.AuthenticationHelper.HasPermissions(User, "Accounting") == true)
{
    <span>User has access to Accounting</span>
}
else
{
    <span>User has no access to Accounting</span>
}
```

And then for actual web pages I'm essentially doing that same thing but in the controller and redirecting them to a different view if they do not have permissions.

Is this a secure way of doing this or are there security flaws? Could someone smart enough find a way around this? I need to make sure under no circumstance can the users in one group see stuff intended for another group. Thanks. Appreciate any advice.

EDIT: Adding Controller Code on request.

```
public ActionResult Dashboard()
    {
        using (Data.WebAppsCoreContext _context = new Data.WebAppsCoreContext())
        {
            var securityRepo = new SecurityRepository(_context);
            var metricBool = securityRepo.Metrics(AuthenticationHelper.GetGroups(User), "Metrics");

            if (metricBool == true)
            {
                //return normal view
                return View();
            }
            else
            {
                //return alternate view
                return View("/Something/Something/");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: share your controller code also for better understanding of your question.

Comment: What is `AuthenticationHelper.HasPermissions` doing? How is it determining that the user is in the group?

Comment: @GabrielLuci I am using ((System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity)user.Identity).Claims.Where(i => i.Type == "groups").Select(i => i.Value.ToString()).ToList(); to find out if the user is in the group.  This works well and does restrict access.  Just wondering if there is a better practice.

Comment: @शेखर I added the controller code.  I can confirm the code works correct and retrieves the groups.  My only question is if this method is secure or if there is a better practice to achieve the same result.